# How do I horizontally center align my webpage for both mobile and desktop view?

Tags: html, css, alignment, styling, centering

In my website the section is left aligned. How can I fix this? How do I horizontally center align my webpage for both mobile and desktop view? I tried center-align block elements by setting both the left and right margins to auto but that is not work. The website's look - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyX1d.jpg - On desktop

Smaller screen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONtbo.jpg

The index.html and css down.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Product Listing</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
      <script src="assets/js/search.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Viga" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <!-- <button onclick="toggle_light_mode()">Toggle Light/Dark Mode</button> -->
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="../home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../videoPage/index.html">Video</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../productPage/index.html">Products</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../philosophy/index.html">Philosophy</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../meetTheTeam/index.html">Team</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../meetTheTeam/indexhtml">Promo</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../beautifulirondisplay/index.html">New</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../grid/index.html">Gallery</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../timeline.html">Timeline</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="../concept/index.html">Concept</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="..//index.html">Me</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-primary text-white tombol" href="../contactUs/index.html">Reach Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- akhir Navbar -->
      <table width="20%">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
            <input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Please enter a search term.."
              title="Type in a name" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    
      <label>Price:</label>
      <select onchange="doSomething(event)" id="myDropdown">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-- Select an option --</option>
        <option value="Lowest to Highest">Lowest to Highest</option>
        <option value="Highest to Lowest">Highest to Lowest</option>
      </select>
    
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    
      
    
      <section class="products">
        <div class="product-card">
          <div class="product-image">
            <img src="assets/img/coat-01.jpeg" />
          </div>
          <div class="product-info">
            <h5>Summer</h5>
            <h6>$82.99</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="product-card">
          <div class="product-image">
            <img src="assets/img/coat-02.jpeg" />
          </div>
          <div class="product-info">
            <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
            <h6>$19.99</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="product-card">
          <div class="product-image">
            <img src="assets/img/coat-03.jpeg" />
          </div>
          <div class="product-info">
            <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
            <h6>$1009.99</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="product-card">
          <div class="product-image">
            <img src="assets/img/coat-04.jpeg" />
          </div>
          <div class="product-info">
            <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
            <h6>$49.99</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="product-card">
          <div class="product-image">
            <img src="assets/img/coat-05.jpeg" />
          </div>
          <div class="product-info">
            <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
            <h6>$23</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    
    
      <script src="sort.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

````
    ```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; }
    
    /\* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers \*/
    
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
    
    body { line-height: 1; }
    
    ol, ul { list-style: none; }
    
    blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
    
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ’’; content: none; }
    
    /\* remember to define visible focus styles! :focus{ outline:?????; } \*/
    
    /\* remember to highlight inserts somehow! \*/
    
    ins { text-decoration: none; }
    
    del { text-decoration: line-through; }
    
    table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
    
    /*------------------------------------*$MAIN \*------------------------------------\*/
    
    @import url([https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400), 300, 500); body { margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; max-width: 1240px; font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; background-color: #f6f6f6; }
    
    /\* Typography \*/
    
    h1 { font-size: 28px; font-weight: 300; flex: 1; }
    
    h5 { font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.7em; }
    
    h6 { color: #666; font-size: 14px; }
    
    /\* Product Layout \*/
    
    .product-filter { display: flex; padding: 30px 0; }
    
    .sort { display: flex; align-self: flex-end; }
    
    .collection-sort { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
    
    .collection-sort:first-child { padding-right: 20px; }
    
    label { color: #666; font-size: 10px; font-weight: 500; line-height: 2em; text-transform: uppercase; }
    
    .products { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
    
    .product-card { display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 2%; flex: 1 16%; background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
    
    .product-image img { width: 100%; }
    
    .product-info { margin-top: auto; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; }
    
    @media (max-width: 920px) { .product-card { flex: 1 21%; } .products .product-card:first-child, .products .product-card:nth-child(2) { flex: 2 46%; } }
    
    @media (max-width: 600px) { .product-card { flex: 1 46%; } }
    
    @media (max-width: 480px) { h1 { margin-bottom: 20px; } .product-filter { flex-direction: column; } .sort { align-self: flex-start; } }
    
    body {
    
    background-image: url("picture.jpg"); }
````

Comment: Better format your code and divide it into sections with some explanations to clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're not really using bootstrap correctly. I recommend you browse the basics on their website starting here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/

As for direct answer to your question. The class which centers content in bootstrap is called 'container'. You're actually already using it in nav element, that's wht it is already centered.

So to center both sections of your site - you should go for this solution:

```
  <div class="container"> - this was added to open a container 
  <!-- akhir Navbar -->
  <table width="20%">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
        <input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Please enter a search term.."
          title="Type in a name" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <label>Price:</label>
  <select onchange="doSomething(event)" id="myDropdown">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-- Select an option --</option>
    <option value="Lowest to Highest">Lowest to Highest</option>
    <option value="Highest to Lowest">Highest to Lowest</option>
  </select>


 
  <section class="products">

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="assets/img/coat-01.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Summer</h5>
        <h6>$82.99</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="assets/img/coat-02.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
        <h6>$19.99</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="assets/img/coat-03.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
        <h6>$1009.99</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="assets/img/coat-04.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
        <h6>$49.99</h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="assets/img/coat-05.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <h5>Winter Jacket</h5>
        <h6>$23</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div> - this was added to close container
```

Apart from that your code has some unopened elements - such a  - should be revised.